# How to do a cron job every 72 minutes

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, hour

How would I get a cron job to run every 72 minutes? Or some not so pretty number like that?

Comment: Why does it have to be 72 minutes?

Comment: Doesn't have to be, just something that's not a nice even number.

Answer (score 43):

Since `cron` runs jobs time-based, not interval-based, there's no blindingly simple way to do it.  However, although it's a bit of a hack, you can set up multiple lines in `crontab` until you find the common denominator. Since you want a job to run every 72 minutes, it must execute at the following times:

- 00:00
- 01:12
- 02:24
- 03:36
- 04:48
- 06:00
- 07:12
- ...

As you can see, the pattern repeats every 6 hours with 5 jobs. So, you will have 5 lines in your `crontab`:

```
0  0,6,12,18  * * * command
12 1,7,13,19  * * * command
24 2,8,14,20  * * * command
36 3,9,15,21  * * * command
48 4,10,16,22 * * * command
```

The other option, of course, is to create a wrapper daemon or shell script that executes and sleeps for the desired time until stopped.

Answer (score 26):

Use at (man at).  Have your app or startup script calculate a startup time 72 minutes in the future and schedule itself to run again before it starts working.

Available on windows xp and vista too.

Here's an example for gnu/linux: at -f command.sh now + 72 minutes

Comment: s/schedule it/schedule itself to run again/

Comment: Hopefully this becomes the accepted answer.  Once you have the job started it can reschedule itself every time it runs.  You might find that you get out of sync, however; so make sure you reschedule your at job as the first thing in your script rather than the last.

Answer (score 4):

You could always take the approach of triggering cron every minute, and having your script exit out immediately if it's been run more recently than 72 minutes ago.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use cron...

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ] 
do
     sleep 4320
     echo "Put your program here" &
done
```

Comment: Be careful if the program crashes, you'll need to restart it. Also, after a machine reboot, the program will not be running, you'll have to start it.

Comment: Yes, better off making it a daemon and using monit for example to keep it running.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly do this from cron/crontab.

Cron jobs are run on a specific schedule, not on a specific interval.

One alternative would be to work out a schedule that approximated your "every 72 minutes" by running at midnight, 1:12, 2:24, 3:36, ..., and stretching it out to approximate hitting up at midnight.  Your crontab file could specify all of these times as times to execute.

Another alternative would be to have a separate application handle the scheduling, and fire your application.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set exactly 20 tasks for this - i.e. set one at 00:00, next one at 01:12, next one at 02:24, etc.

20 iterations make a full day.

Unfortunately, this is the only way to do it, as cron tasks are set up in a fixed schedule beforehand instead of being run, say, "after X minutes the last task was executed".

Answer (score -7):

Uh I know this is long overdue, but I was looking at some scheduling issues and saw this question.

Just do this in your crontab

*/72 * * * * /home/script.sh

Comment: This will not work, minutes are 0-59 and anything over 30 minutes will post at x past, ie 34 will post at 34 mintues past, not every 34 minutes.

Comment: I just tested this and the result of `*/72 * * * * date >> cron-over-72.out` under CentOS 7 is the job runs one time per hour, on the hour.