# What is the Cron expression for every 100 hours in Azure Function Timer trigger?

Tags: azure-functions, timer-trigger

I am trying to create a timer trigger which will run every 100 hours interval.I have tried implementing `0 0 */100 * * *` but it is triggering it every day. I have very basic idea about cron expression but couldn't formulate the actual expression for the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cronjob every 25 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417098/cronjob-every-25-hours)

Comment: The solution posted there are asking me to write a separate shell script to achieve it. My question is can I not get it done with the existing cron expression?

Answer (score 0):

`100 hours == 4 days + 4 hours`

Suppose the job starts to execute at 00:00 AM, then you can try `0 4 */4 * *` which means *'At 04:00 on every 4th day-of-month'*.

Comment: Are you suggesting `0 0 4 */4 * *` ? (I think you are missing one in the expression.) But the interval won't be of 100 hours if I do that.

Comment: @Akash in my answer cron was built according to UNIX Cron Format. It consists of 5 fields (no field for 'seconds'). Which type of cron expression do you use? If you add another 0 to the leftmost part as you mentioned ('second' field), cron will mean `At 04:00:00 on every 4th day-of-month`. 100 hours depend on when you are going to schedule this cron expression ('hour' field can vary).

Comment: I am using the cron expression in Azure Function Timer trigger, if I use your expression it would start the trigger 4 days later at 4 a.m. and the remaining will be just a 4 day gap, meaning 96 hours.