# Cronjob every x minutes from 9 to 23 hours

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I need to configure cronjob at specific time, like every 50 minutes from 9 to 23 pm.
And I am trying

- `*/50 9-23 ***`

But it runs at 9:50 and also at 10:00, I need some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181949/how-do-set-cron-to-run-my-script-every-40mins-25mins

Comment: I saw that, and actually they made 2 cron jobs for 40 minutes interval, for 0,40 */2 and 20 1,3,5.... but its not really good solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time range you define it is converted into:

```
9 50
10 40
11 30
12 20
13 10
14 00
15 50 -
16 40
17 30
18 20
19 10
20 00
20 50 -
21 40
22 30
```

So that you need to define these different cronjobs:

```
50 9,15,20 * * *
40 10,16,21 * * *
30 11,17,22 * * *
20 12,18 * * *
10 13,19 * * *
00 14,20 * * *
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. But is there any other way to make it more flexible,I mean f.e. if I need every 48, or 40 minutes then need to change a lot:)

Comment: Well, if you write all the times then you can group them. With 40 will get many similarities, just three groups.

Comment: Why did you unaccept? It is not my fault that cronjob is not that flexible :)