# Run cron every 245 minutes

Tags: linux, cron

How to run cron every **245 minutes**?
`*/5 */4 * * * command` - this variant is true?
Or need to run?
 `*/5 4 * * * command`

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745901/how-to-do-a-cron-job-every-72-minutes

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is

```
5 */4 * * * command
```

That mean the job will run on minute: 5 of every 4 hours

Comment: Which means it runs every 240 minutes, not every 245 minutes.

Comment: let set to * */4 * * * command

Comment: That's even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Below is correct for Red Hat Based Linux( **RHEL,Fedora,Centos etc.** ) or maybe on **Ubuntu** too.

```
5 */4 * * * command.
```

But for **Solaris** Based Operating System, You can use below one :

```
5 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * command
```

But this runs every 240 minutes.

As per your requirement its not possible with normal cron.

You can check the replacement of cron like the one given below:

https://mesos.github.io/chronos/

Comment: That runs every 240 minutes, not every 245 minutes.