# Crone to be executed every 40 minutes and 3 hours

Tags: jenkins, cron, cron-task

i am looking to execute a crone job in Linux. it should run every 3 hour and 40 minutes.

I have tried */40 */3 * * * command, I am not getting this properly executed.

thanks in advance .

Comment: that's not possible with cron. you can only specify repeat intervals for the individual time elements, not for arbitrary times lengths that COMBINE those time elements. you'd need to use `at` and have the job reschedule itself

Comment: thanks for answering , what do you mean by using <b> at </b>

Comment: `at` is a cousin of cron, for one-shot jobs scheduled "at" specific times. run your job, then have it reschedule itself with `at` for `now() + 220 minutes`

Comment: thanks, I got some idea as  "at -f command.sh now + 72 minutes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron is time based, not interval based, and the interval 3 hour 40 minutes i.e. 220 minutes is not a factor of the number of minutes in a day i.e. 24x60=1440, so the event is not a recurring event. so there is no way to use cron. if the interval is a factor of 1440, it's possible to use cron, you may refer to [How to do a cron job every 72 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745901/how-to-do-a-cron-job-every-72-minutes)