# How can I run a Background job with Hangfire every n minutes/hours/days

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

I have been working recentelly with Hangfire I have created RecurringJobs,because a ReccuringJob only runs with a cron expression like:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule a job at a given time frequently
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"> Type of the function< </typeparam>
        /// <param name="jobId"> the job Id </param>
        /// <param name="methodToTrigger">he method that will be triggered at a given time</param>
        /// <param name="cronExpression">Expression that will define the frequency of trigger for the job</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task SchedulReccurentJob<T>
            (string jobId, Expression<Func<T, Task>> methodToTrigger, string cronExpression)
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<T>(jobId, methodToTrigger, cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

I get the cron expressions via these expressions (they work just fine):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an expression for launching job every n minutes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="minutes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string EveryMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        return $"0 */{minutes} * ? * *"; // cant set minutes > 59
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an expression for launching job every n hours 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hours"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string EveryHours(int hours)
    {
        return $"0 0 0/{hours} 1/1 * ? *";  // cant set hours > 23
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an expression for launching job every days at given hour and minute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="days"></param>
    /// <param name="hour"></param>
    /// <param name="minute"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string EveryDaysAtHourAndMinute(int days, int hour, int minute)
    {
        return $"0 {minute} {hour} */{days} * ?"; // cant set days > 31
    }
```

My problem is that I want to run a specific job every given minutes , or  every given hours, or maybe every given days but with the same hour/minute.

I took a look on the cron expression it's apprentelly not possible:
[image]

Do u have any ideas ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tried http://www.cronmaker.com/ or https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html ?

Comment: Yes even tried it on Hangfire directelly

Comment: And what's the issue you are facing? Can you give an example of schedule which you want to create cron for?

Comment: For example using my function every 70 minutes wont work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745901/how-to-do-a-cron-job-every-72-minutes